# Is there a cheaper (performance-wise) alternative for changing alpha values?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, transparency, alpha

I've noticed that setting (decreasing) the alpha value of a view is a very expensive operation. I've tried using it in my view/page transformers and I have no choice but to just remove it.

And it's not just limited to transformers and the likes. I've also once decreased the alpha of a seekbar and a FAB which sit on top of a listview (i.e. not part of the list adapter) and to my surprise, my listview's scrolling performance suddenly hits rock bottom.

And even worse, when I tried to change the alpha of an imageview (4dp thick containing a simple gradient to mimic a shadow) which is part of a list adapter, my activity's overall performance suddenly dropped (lagging even in just a simple pager swipe/list scroll).

So does anyone know any alternative? Thank you very much.

Comment: On ImageViews you should change the alpha of the drawable, not the view itself for better performance

Comment: Is your image scaled correctly or is it being scaled dynamically? You should provide a resource that is scaled correctly for better performance.

Comment: So I'll try setting up the drawable's transparency instead. Thanks.